# Predict one random variable from another with same seed

Tags: python, numpy, random

Given the same seed, is it possible to predict one output from the other, with different type and range?

e.g.

```
np.random.seed(100)

x = np.random.randint(0, 16, 2)

np.random.seed(100)

y = np.random.randint(0, 256)
```

In this example I have `x` as a 2-element integer array with range 0-15 and `y` as a integer scalar with range 0-255.

My question is in general, not limited to the example above, under which condition it is possible to predict `y` given `x`? Assume the observer knows `x`, type and range of `x` and `y`, but not the seed itself.

Any discussion of sufficient or necessary conditions for predictability will be useful.

Comment: without knowing the seed? I don't think so, the point of pseudo random numbers is that it is virtually impossible to predict without figuring out the seed but that depends heavily on what algorithm is used internally.

Comment: oh wait you are only generating a single number in both cases! ok then maybe, it would require knowledge on the internals of numpy randomness.

Comment: If you don't know the seed, and you can only obtain 1 number for x, then I don't think it will be possible to figure out y, as this will require to guess the seed, which I believe is not possible given your above case.

Comment: No, but you can make a good guess of `y` from `x[0]`. In the example above `y` will be a value such that `y % 16 == x[0]`. So given a seed of `1002`, `x` will be  `[7, 1]` and y will be `103` which is congruent to 7 mod 16.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the seed, you can predict any value at any position, because the seed is used to build *reproducible pseudo random sequences*. If you do not know the seed, you cannot predict a value from the previous values.

If you have 2 sequences from the same seed *and they are trivially bound*, you can predict one sequence from the other one or at least know that the values will be from a smaller set.

Your example contain trivially bound sequences. Both are int sequences, one (x) uses 4 bits, one (y) uses 8 bits. At same rank, x = y % 16. That means that x is fully known if you know y, but if you know x, each y value has 16 possibilities (instead of 256).

Demo:

```
np.seed(100)
np.random.randint(0, 256, 3)
-> np.array([8, 24, 67])
np.seed(100)
np.random.randint(0, 16, 3)      # we have y % 16
-> np.array([8, 8, 3])
```

Another example or trivially bound sequences is when one is just shifted by a constant value

```
np.seed(100)
np.random.randint(2, 258, 3)    # we will have y + 2 here...
-> np.array([10, 26, 69])
```

Any two sequences from the same seed will have some kind of dependency, but if their relation is not trivial, you will only be able to know that dependency through a detailed knowledge of the pseudo-random implementation... And as far as I am concerned I have not that knowledge ;-), so I can only speak for trivial cases.

Comment: "cannot predict a value from the previous values" is the definition of a cryptographically secure PRNG.  non-CSPRNGs can be [much easier to predict](https://www.pcg-random.org/predictability.html).  recent versions of numpy use PCG64 which makes them much harder to predict than the Mersenne Twister that was previously used by default where you'd need 624 values to know the sequence